# Reading a rdf file

Tags: oraclereports

How can I read a RDF file. I tried opening it in with Notepad++ but it doesn't show correctly.

The file creates a report and I need to understand the file logic on how the report is created.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show correctly? What did you expect and what do you see? What is the serialization - Turtle, XML?

Comment: How can I find the serialization?

Comment: To be honest I have not worked with any RDF file earlier and in notepad++ the current format which I see is not readable mostly. I will try and show a screenshot.

Comment: Do. That might help.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov Image added

Comment: ...and this is a file you can open with, say, Protégé?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157858/discussion-between-sourav-mehra-and-ivo-velitchkov).

Comment: @SouravMehra, this "RDF" is for "Report Definition File" or something like, not for "Resource Description Framework". Related tags probably are [tag:rdl] or [tag:oraclereports].

Comment: @StanislavKralin Yes this is exactly a Oracle Report.

Comment: @StanislavKralin So how can now I read this?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++, or any advanced text editor for that matter, opens RDF files. The structure of each RDF file depends on the serialization used.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is to convert the binary into a text format. Oracle provides the `rwconverter` utility, which can convert an `rdf` report into its corresponding `xml` format.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28389_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_cla002.htm#i634710

Comment: If you need the IDE, have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/reports/downloads/index.html

Comment: Can you help me with this conversion if you have this utility.

Comment: The utility is provided as part of the Oracle Forms and Reports Middleware product. Have you installed it? May I ask what is your specific requirement?

Comment: My requirement is that I simply want to view a rdf oracle report (maybe in XML) and just delete one line from it which I no longer require in the report.

Comment: Then you'll need to use the Report Builder tool. It is part of the Forms and Reports product i mentioned earlier.

Comment: Do you have the tool handy with you?. I just need it one time so is it possible for you to convert and send back the XML to me?

Comment: There is no need to bother with the xml. Just use the tool for building reports provided by Oracle.

Comment: I installed the Oracle Forms and Reports. But there reportbuilder doesnt work.

Comment: What is the error? You could ask a new question for getting help.